# Java: "cannot resolve method" when using building pattern with generic constructor

Tags: java, generics, constructor, builder

I have a generic class with a constructor and builder method:

```
public class FilterBuilder<T> {
    public FilterBuilder() {

    }

    public FilterBuilder<T> add(T x) {
        ...
        return this;
    }
}
```

I instantiate, yet add doesn't work from constructor call:

```
FilterBuilder<String> filter = new FilterBuilder().add("test");
```

This gives *'Cannot resolve method add'* error in Intellij. I have to do this to make it work:

```
FilterBuilder<String> filter = new FilterBuilder();
filter.add("test");
```

but why?

Comment: The first snippet works just fine, except for a raw-type warning. Are you **sure** that line causes the error? Could you share the exact text?

Comment: I also tried that and there is no error

Comment: There will not be any error. Check you code please.

Comment: I tested both in InteliJ, no issue both compiled

Comment: what version of IntelliJ are you using?

Answer (score 1):

With your actual code, I think that the problem occurs as you specify the diamond operator `<>` :

```
FilterBuilder<String> filter = new FilterBuilder<>().add("test");
```

Raw types should not generate compilation errors but warnings but if your IDE configuration is stricter on this matter.

It is a compilation error specific to IDE as they consider  `new FilterBuilder<>()` as a raw type even if the type of the declared builder is `<String>`.

By compiling with javac, no compilation error while on Eclipse Oxygen, I have the issue.

I suspect that the diamond operator support was not implemented in IDEs to allow the chaining of the instantiation to an instance method invocation.

As workaround you could do things in two times :

```
FilterBuilder<String> filter = new FilterBuilder<>();
filter.add("test");
```

or specify the generic twice :

```
FilterBuilder<String> filter = new FilterBuilder<String>().add("test");
```

Comment: might as well do not store the builder anywhere and just use: `new FilterBuilder<String>().add("test");`

Comment: If you pass it as a method parameter I suppose ?  I will create a big parameter :)

Comment: well builder are supposedly here to create an object and *I* prefer to not pass the builders arround, but I'm guessing that might be a case